# ¿Como imprimir/formatear un puntero para ver la dirección de la memoria de una variable? Unity + C#

Tags: c#, punteros, unity, formato

Estoy buscando la forma de ver la dirección de la memoria de una variable para saber si está siendo compartida por varias instacias de la clase (variable única) o por el contrario se ha heredado una variable diferente para cada instancia. En principio sopecho que es única por estar declarda como **static**. Pero podría ser que no ya que el código completo no me da fallos y estoy seguro que debería dar fallos si fuera única porque es extremadamente dependiente de esta variable.

Lo que estoy haciendo es lo siguiente:

```
//------------------------------------------------------
namespace AnimatorExtensionMethods
{
    public static class AnimationsHandler                                
    {
        public static string stateName;   //nombre de la animacion actual
        public static AnimatorClipInfo[] clipInfo;

        public static string GetCurrentClipName(this Animator animator)
        {        
           clipInfo = animator.GetCurrentAnimatorClipInfo(0);
           if (clipInfo.Length > 0)
             return clipInfo[0].clip.name;
           else
            return "NULL";
        }

        public static void Update(this Animator animator)
        {
            stateName = GetCurrentClipName(animator);       
        }

        public static string GetStateName(this Animator animator)
        {
            return stateName;   
        }
}

//------------------------------------------------------
using AnimatorExtensionMethods;

public class FireBall : MonoBehaviour
{
 public Text infoText;
 public GameObject player;
 Animator playerAnimator;
 Animator animator;



void Start()
{
    playerAnimator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
    animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
}

 void Update()
 {
       animator.Update();

        unsafe
        {   
            fixed (char* p1 = animator.GetStateName())
            {
                Debug.Log((IntPtr)(p1));  **//-->Aquí es donde tengo el problema**
            }
        }


        unsafe
        {
            fixed (char* p2 = playerAnimator.GetStateName())
            {
                infoText.text = "" + (int)p2;  **//-->Aquí es donde tengo el problema**
            }
        }
 }
}
//------------------------------------------------------
```

Tal y como está ahora lo que obtengo es un número enorme que cambia a gran velocidad.
Y lo que espero obtener es un número hexadecimal que no cambie, algo asi **0x1315464**.

Pues basicamente a eso se reduce el problema ¿Cómo formateo el puntero para ver una salida por pantalla con este formato **0x1315464** y constante? Gracias!!

Comment: No se si logro entender tu problema pero cuando trabajas con clases trabajas con valores por referencia, entonces si creas un objeto de clase, luego este lo asignas a un segundo, y el segundo cambias algun valor de una propiedad, tambien se esta cambiando en tu primer objeto de mismo tipo, por ser un valor de referencia y apuntan a un lugar de memoria. Si es static el objeto se crea apenas inicia el programa y en teoria (puedo estar equivocado) el GC no lo limpia, lo cual a tu Clase si detecta que no es usada se la limpia de la memoria.

Comment: La clase es static.. hay una sola instancia de la misma en todo tu sistema... No necesitas ver el puntero de memoria... algo esta cambiando el valor...

Comment: Gracias a los dos por vuestra respuesta. Eso es lo que suponia. Lo que pasa es que  que acabo de convertir esa clase a static y el programa sigue funcionando correctamente y es algo que no me esperaba porque las animaciones del juego dependen de esa variable para reproducirse completamente. Y lo hacen incluso reproduciendose dos animaciones simultaneamente. No comprendo porque pasa esto. Debe ser cosa del Animator. De todas formas creo que voy a cambiar el código  para asegurarme de que esa variable no sea estática y no de problemas en el futuro. Gracias y Saludos!!